# Como validar um usuário do AD através de um campo usando uma app MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, active-directory

Estou desenvolvendo uma app Sharepoint em MVC que cria um usuário do AD no Sharepoint, então preciso de um campo similar ao `SharePoint:PeopleEditor` que existe no ASPX, para validar esses usuários na hora do cadastro.

Existe alguma alternativa? Ou alguma outra forma que posso fazer essa validação?

Comment: Como está o código disso?